# Anyway of converting this to outputting digital readings?

Tags: electrical-engineering, design

is there anyway of converting this machine into giving me digital readings?

I bought it on ebay the other day and I am planning on cleaning it up and getting it looking good as new.
[image]

Comment: You are likely going to have to add a lot more detail if you want an answer. At the very least put some information about the device into your question. As it is right now, the picture is required for any sense as to what you are asking.

Comment: To save everyone else's time,  this model does not have an RS232 or any other type of digital interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few different ways of doing something like this.

1. I believe that type of dial uses a magnetic field to move the needle. A well placed Hall effect sensor could do the trick. This is not invasive and also relatively hidden.
2. A hall effect sensor may be a bit complex to place and calibrate. Another option would be to tap into the reading and pull the voltage generating the current for the needle. Link this to an ADC in a micro-controller (Arduino, MSP430, etc.) and you should get an decent result. [Electron microscope image capture via microcontroller (with drill bit animation)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruuxn2u3yao), I highly recommend this video, very similar to your project.
3. Use a Raspberry-Pi and a Pi-camera. If you are more of a fan of programming as opposed to circuits you can have a pi-camera attached to device and read out where it is pointing with some relatively simple code.

Comment: Any device that puts out a voltage , regardless of how the voltage is generated , can be converted to digital by an A to D converter. Once in digital form you can display the output in any digital form you like. Pick up a good book (or something online) that shows you how to do this, it will be a good learning experience  :-)

Comment: You beat me to it, at least the camera-to-digital transform part :-)